# "My little Trump" - Is Frank referring to Donald Trump during Nazi report?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, comedy, shameless

In Season 6 Episode 7 of Shameless, Chuckle Slott was giving a report on Nazis.

After the report, Frank Gallagher says:

> Thats my little **Trump**.<sup>Capitalized?</sup>

I'm not sure if he's referring to [Donald Trump](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump), or if this is a reference to something else.

I didn't care much for/read into Donald Trump until his campaigns for presidency, so I'm not aware of how racist he may have appeared before the campaign. I understand he has made many racist remarks, but tends to contradict himself quite often.

---

## Question

Is Frank referring to Donald Trump?

Comment: If you are able to rewatch the episode, you can turn on subtitles to see how it is capitalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Frank referring to Donald Trump?

Yes.

I would just like to say I am not all for Trump, I am simply expressing my opinion on this.

In the ending credits of the episode, Chuckie Slott got himself in a bit of trouble when he turned in a book report on Adolf Hitler’s *Mein Kampf*. He said like this :

> “The superiors put all the inferiors in bad summer camps because they didn’t want them crossing the border and ruining the neighborhood,”
>
> “And that is why Adolf Hitler is a great American leader.”

This speech, of course, left his fellow students, the teacher, and the assembled parents stunned because he refer Hitler as american leader.

Frank then stepped in after a brief look of shock and disbelief by the rest of the children and declared Chuckie a `“young Trump”` saying :

> German, but I think you've made your point here, my young Trump.

Donald Trump’s rhetoric doesn’t need to be rehashed here. If you are even an occasional consumer of American news, you know that Trump is running on what is accurately described as a Fascist platform.

It may seem a bit excessive to actually compare Trump to Hitler.

Shameless often has fun with politics, mainly using Frank’s unhinged rants both to voice the conservative viewpoint and to critique it by presenting it in its terrifyingly-unglued glory

Comment: I think you are generally correct.However, I think the nuance is lost: Frank is calling the kid an uninformed white nationalist, not making a Hitler comparison specifically. Deserved or not, intentional or not Trump has a propensity for getting facts a little wrong.